# Manipulating/accessing table data in XSL FO

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am making a template in XSL FO to produce a PDF that is essentially a formatted version of an initial XML file, and i was wondering if it is possible to access the value stored in a specific cell or cluster of cells in a table, for example to produce a total value over a range of values within the table as you would in excel, or if you are limited only to using xpath expressions to simply retrieve the same data and have it directly output the result to the cell you wanted in. I have tried giving the cells unique ids, but i do not understand if this allows you to pass the values stored in those cells or not.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Numbers>
    <A>12</A>
    <B>22</B>
    <A>19</A>
    <B>47</B>
    <A>38</A>
    <B>2</B>
</Numbers>
```

Comment: Yes you can do this. How to do it depends on whether you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath function: number sum (node-set)

sum(//Numbers/A) ... all the A's

sum(//Numbers/B) ... all the B's

you could also use position() to get things like the third position to the 5th position ...